# import module in Class, but NameError when using module in class method

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

In my python script, I'm trying to import module in class and use the imported module in the class method.

```
class test:
    import urllib.parse

    def __init__(self, url):
        urlComponents = urllib.parse.urlsplit(url)
```

Howerver, when I try to use the test class, such as

```
test("http://test.com")
```

I get the error:

> NameError: name 'urllib' is not defined

Why import statement in class body do not take effect?

I use python 3.8.1 in windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `import` statement performs a name binding, but names inside the class scope are not directly visible inside methods. This is the same as for any other class name.

```
>>> class Test:
...     a = 2   # bind name on class
...     def get_a(self):
...         return a  # unqualified reference to class attribute
...
>>> Test().get_a()
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

You can refer to any class attribute either through the class or the instance instead. This works for imported names as well.

```
class test:
    import urllib.parse

    def __init__(self, url):
        #               V refer to attribute in class
        urlComponents = self.urllib.parse.urlsplit(url)
```

Note that there isn't any advantage to binding a module inside a class, with the exception of hiding the name from the global scope. Usually, you should import at the global scope.

```
import urllib.parse

class test:

    def __init__(self, url):
        #               V refer to global module
        urlComponents = urllib.parse.urlsplit(url)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. This explaination is very clear and helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

It was self.urllib.parse that you were missing.

If you really want to import a module inside a class you must access it from that class:

```
class Test:
    import urllib.parse as ul


    def __init__(self, url):
        urlComponents = self.ul.urlsplit(url)

t1 = Test("www.test.com")  
print(t1)
```

## Result : <**main**.Test at 0x5029>