# Python : Importing a function in a class

Tags: python, class, recursion, nameerror

I am currently coding two classes : TreeBuilder and Codec. Both are coded in "codec.py".
In TreeBuilder, I want to use a function called route, which is coded in another file (route.py). route is a recursive function.
I try importing route in TreeBuilder like so :

```
class TreeBuilder :
    from route import route

    def tree(self):
        ....
        self.tree = route(self.tree)
```

I use a command prompt and type :

```
from codec import Treebuilder, Codec
```

But when I create a TreeBuilder object and try using self.tree(), I get this error :

```
NameError: name 'route' is not defined
```

How should I import the route function to stop having this error ?

Comment: Either outside of the class or inside the method.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [import module in Class, but NameError when using module in class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60236653/import-module-in-class-but-nameerror-when-using-module-in-class-method)

Comment: @schwobaseggl I still get the same error when using it inside the method.

Comment: @AlexandreSenges It is an exercise and one of the rules is that I should only need to import the two classes (TreeBuilder and Codec), and I shouldn't have to import an additional function or module to use TreeBuilder and Codec.

Comment: @Tenchiroxx Why do you want to do the import *in the class* as opposed to outside of it?

Answer (score -1):

I don't see a clear reason why you would want to do that but one way would be:

```
class TreeBuilder :
    route = __import__("route").route

    def tree(self):
        ....
        self.tree = TreeBuilder.route(self.tree)
```

Comment: I doesn't seem to work... I still get the name error doing this.

Comment: It's because of another error in your code, not because of my example. I tested it already. Send me your error message

Comment: I downvoted because this is not an appropriate use of ˋ__import__ˋ. Suggesting it against a regular ˋimportˋ is misleading.